# RecyclerView not refershing even when data set is changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement  pagination with recyclerview. I don't know why but data is refreshing only when there are results in response when there are no results it's not updating.I have filter, sort and location selection; filter and sort are working fine but location selection not working as it api returns empty list for some selections.I have SwipeRefreshLayout in the layout also when i refresh again using swipe refresh ,recyclerview updates after then.

This is  my pagination listener and recyclerview

```
public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


        if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= getTotalPageCount()) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

    public abstract int getTotalPageCount();

    public abstract boolean isLastPage();

    public abstract boolean isLoading(); }
```

This my recyclerview

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getmContext(), AppConstants.GRID_2);
    mProductRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mProductRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    PaginationScrollListener paginationScrollListener = new PaginationScrollListener(gridLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            //Increment page index to load the next one
            CURRENT_PAGE += 1;
            loadNextPage();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    };

    productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(getmContext(), R.layout.b_item_home_product);
    productListAdapter.setiAdapterItemCheckChangeListener(this);
    mProductRecyclerView.setAdapter(productListAdapter);

    mProductRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(paginationScrollListener);


    itemClickDisposable = productListAdapter.getItemClickSubject().subscribe(productId -> {
        UIHelper.getInstance().switchActivity(getmActivity(), ProductInfoActivity.class, UIHelper.ActivityAnimations.LEFT_TO_RIGHT, productId.toString(), AppConstants.K_ID, false);
    });

    viewModel.getProductsLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), responseList -> {
        switch (responseList.status) {
            case LOADING:
                if (CURRENT_PAGE <= TOTAL_PAGE) {
                    showHideBottomProgress(true);
                } else {
                    isLastPage = true;
                }
                if (isFirstPage) {
                    showMainLoading(true);
                }
                break;
            case ERROR:
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (CURRENT_PAGE <= TOTAL_PAGE) {
                    showHideBottomProgress(false);
                }
                if (isFirstPage) {
                    showMainLoading(false);
                } else {
                    isLoading = false;
                }
                showErrorPrompt(responseList.message);
                break;
            case SUCCESS:
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (CURRENT_PAGE <= TOTAL_PAGE) {
                    showHideBottomProgress(false);
                }
                if (isFirstPage) {
                    showMainLoading(false);
                } else {
                    isLoading = false;
                }
                productListAdapter.addProducts(responseList.response);
                break;
        }
    });
```

For loading page and next Page using this methods

```
private void loadFirstPage() {
    isFirstPage = true;
    isLastPage = false;
    resetProductsList();
    viewModel.getProducts(getProductFilter());
}

private void loadNextPage() {
    isFirstPage = false;
    productFilter.setOffset(CURRENT_PAGE);
    viewModel.getProducts(productFilter);
}

public void resetProductsList() {
    productListAdapter.clear();
    productFilter.setOffset(1);

}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_SALE = 1, TYPE_POPULAR = 2, TYPE_LOADING = 3;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResId;
    private List<Product> products;
    private PublishSubject<Integer> itemClickSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    private IAdapterItemCheckChangeListener iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener;
    private IAdapterItemClickListener iAdapterItemClickListener;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<Product> data) {
        mContext = context;
        mResId = resId;
        products = data;
    }

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resId) {
        mContext = context;
        mResId = resId;
        products = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void addProducts(List<Product> newProducts) {
        for (Product product : newProducts) {
            addProduct(product);
        }
    }

    public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
        products.add(newProduct);
        notifyItemInserted(products.size() - 1);
    }

    public void setiAdapterItemCheckChangeListener(IAdapterItemCheckChangeListener iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener) {
        this.iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener = iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener;
    }

    public void setiAdapterItemClickListener(IAdapterItemClickListener iAdapterItemClickListener) {
        this.iAdapterItemClickListener = iAdapterItemClickListener;
    }

    public PublishSubject<Integer> getItemClickSubject() {
        return itemClickSubject;
    }

    // Clean all elements of the recycler

    public void clear() {
        while (getItemCount() > 0) {
            remove(getItem(0));
        }
    }

    public void remove(Product product) {
        int position = products.indexOf(product);
        if (position > -1) {
            products.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public Product getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_SALE:
                return new SaleHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_home_sale, parent, false));
            case TYPE_LOADING:
                return new ProgressItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_pagination, parent, false));
            default:
                return new ProductHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mResId, parent, false));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_POPULAR) {
            ((ProductHolder) holder).setUpProductHolder(products.get(position));
        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOADING) {
        } else {
            ((SaleHolder) holder).setupSaleHolder(products.get(position));
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (products.get(position).getType() == AppConstants.PRODUCT_TYPE.TYPE_SALE) {
            return TYPE_SALE;
        } else {
            return TYPE_POPULAR;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        itemClickSubject.onComplete();

    }

    public class SaleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public SaleHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        private void setupSaleHolder(Product product) {

        }
    }

    public class ProgressItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.progress_wheel)
        ProgressWheel progressWheel;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_error)
        TextView errorMsg;

        public ProgressItemHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        private void bindHolder(NetworkState networkState) {
            if (networkState != null && networkState.getStatus() == NetworkState.Status.LOADING) {
                progressWheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressWheel.spin();
            } else {
                progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressWheel.stopSpinning();
            }

            if (networkState != null && networkState.getStatus() == NetworkState.Status.FAILED) {
                errorMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorMsg.setText(R.string.please_connect_to_your_network);
            } else {
                errorMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    }

    public class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.iv_product_preview_image)
        ImageView productImage;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_product_name)
        TextView productName;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_product_price)
        MagicText productPrice;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_average_rating)
        TextView productRating;
        @BindView(R.id.cb_wishlist)
        CheckBox wishlist;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_product_quality)
        TextView productQuality;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_discount)
        TextView discount;
        @BindView(R.id.container_original_price)
        ConstraintLayout originalPrice;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_original_price)
        TextView priceWithoutDiscount;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_brand_name)
        TextView brandName;

        public ProductHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            RxView.clicks(itemView)
                    .map(unit -> getAdapterPosition())
                    .subscribe(itemClickSubject);
            wishlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener == null) return;
            if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                iAdapterItemCheckChangeListener.onCheckChange(isChecked, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

        public void setUpProductHolder(Product product) {
            try {
                productImage.setImageDrawable(null);

                if (product.getBrandLabel() == null) {
                    brandName.setText("");

                } else {
                    brandName.setText(product.getBrandLabel());
                }
                productName.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.product_full_name, product.getName()));

                wishlist.setChecked(product.getWishList() >= 1);

//                productPrice.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.price_with_currency, product.getPrice()));


                float avgRating = product.getAverageRating() != null ? product.getAverageRating() : AppConstants.DEFAULT_RATING;
                String ratingTrimed = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f", avgRating);
                productRating.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.average_rating, avgRating));
                productQuality.setText(product.getQuality() != null ? product.getQuality() : "");


                if (product.getDiscount() > 0) {
                    String fullPrice = mContext.getString(R.string.price_in_currency, product.getFinalPrice());
                    productPrice.change(fullPrice, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack), 16, "normal", product.getFinalPrice());

                    discount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    discount.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.discount_with_percent, product.getDiscount()));
                    originalPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    priceWithoutDiscount.setText(product.getPrice());

                } else {
                    String fullPrice = mContext.getString(R.string.price_in_currency, product.getPrice());
                    productPrice.change(fullPrice, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack), 16, "normal", product.getPrice());

                    discount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    originalPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (product.getFree() > 0) {
                    String fullPrice = mContext.getString(R.string.price_in_currency, product.getSpecialPrice());
                    productPrice.change(fullPrice, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack), 16, "normal", product.getSpecialPrice().toString());

                    originalPrice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    priceWithoutDiscount.setText(product.getPrice());

                    discount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    discount.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.discount_with_percent, AppConstants.DISCOUNT_100));
                }
                Glide.with(mContext).load(product.getImages().get(0).getValue()).apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .error(R.drawable.no_image_available)
                        .centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_available)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).into(productImage);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "error");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (iAdapterItemClickListener == null) return;
            iAdapterItemClickListener.onAdapterItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


}
```

Here i am implementing pagination
[Image Preview Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEiD.jpg)

**Edit 1:**
When Loading First Page

{"discount":false,"limit":10,"offset":1,"order":"DESC","sort":"rating"}
Response : [When loading first page](https://jsonblob.com/e96cfaa9-2edf-11eb-9b25-51075b17116f)

When Loading Next Page

{"city":"Kazakhstan","discount":false,"limit":10,"offset":1,"order":"DESC","sort":"rating"}

Reponse : [When loading page again with other filter](https://jsonblob.com/6a480a69-2ee0-11eb-9b25-b13122c3a100)

Answer (score 0):

As per your adapter class coding part, You are not handling empty list.

In below method you are adding products one by one to adapter's product list. when the list is empty, loop is not working and the list is not changed so the values are same as previous response.

```
 public void addProducts(List<Product> newProducts) {
    for (Product product : newProducts) {
        addProduct(product);
    }
 }
```

Add below code snippet in your method

```
 public void addProducts(List<Product> newProducts) {
     if(newProducts!= null && !newProducts.isEmpty()){
       for (Product product : newProducts) 
         addProduct(product);
     }else{
        // either you can set empty list
        this.products = newProducts;
       //or you can clear the list values
       products.clear();
       notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am also clearing adapter before calling the api

`public void resetProductsList() {
    productListAdapter.clear();
    productFilter.setOffset(1);

}`
but recylerview doesn't seem to update after this.

Comment: Recycler view is inside a fragment if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried the code in Answer? It will help you.

Comment: No still same result.

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: Actually initial data is loading when i am calling loadFirstPage() which returns some data but when i am changing location as mentioned in attached screenshot and calling the api again with different filter it returns no data in response  but recyclerview is still showing old data but in actual recyclerview should be empty.

Comment: share json response in both cases

Comment: Edited with json response.

Comment: Response is looking fine, what is functionality of below method viewModel.getProducts(productFilter);

Comment: It calls the api to get Products List , I am using MVVM approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get the problem. It might be issue related to thread.

> Issue : Pagination screen was a fragment and the location spinner was
> in activity within a toolbar. I was using `getActivity.findViewById()`
> to get the spinner and populate the data inside that fragment itself. I
> had a listener set for spinner so whenever item is clicked i was
> calling the api within the fragment.

I have solved it by using Event Bus to communicate with that fragment. Now I am populating spinner within activity itself. Whenever item is clicked from that spinner i am firing event ; this event i have subscribed in the fragment where i am implementing pagination so on that event api is called. It's working as expected now.